# Functions $f:\varnothing\to\varnothing$, how many are there?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many functions from an empty set to itself can we define?
I have found that there is exactly one function from an empty set to any non-empty set. But now I just want to know is this also true if both sets are empty or not?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the definition of a function as a set of ordered pairs fulfilling certain properties, we see that the empty set is a function from the empty set to the empty set, just as it is a function from the empty set to any other set.

---

Definition of a function: A set $f$ is a function from the set $X$ to the set $Y$ if it consists of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ such that each $x\in X$ appears in exactly one such pair.

Answer (score 2):

In set theory a function $f:A\to B$ is usually a set of pairs with some additional properties. So you write $f(a)=b$ instead of $(a,b)\in f$ where $a$ is from the domain $A$ and $b$ from the codomain $B$. If domain and codomain are empty then $f$ can contain no pairs, hence $f=\varnothing$. Strange but I guess this counts as a function. And it is the unique one.

Comment: If this is true that there is unique function that it solves an indeterminate form 0^0=1.

Comment: @Rattanverma $0^0$ is only an indeterminate if your exponent can get arbitrarily close to $0$. If you're limited to natural numbers or integers as exponents, $0^0$ may be defined as $1$ quite naturally, for instance through combinatorial arguments (if you have a keypad with no buttons on it, and want to make a password that doesn't have any characters in it, you can actually make exactly one such password with the given keypad).

Comment: @Rattanverma I would not draw the conclusion to $0^0=1$ as in J.G.'s answer. $0^0$ is not defined in general. The definition $0^0=1$ makes sense *here*, but might be different somewhere else. The formula that there are $|A|^{|B|}$ many functions should not be naively extended to $A=B=\varnothing$ *except* you set $0^0=1$ *in this case*.

Comment: @Rattan: You are mixing two completely separate things. The one is $\lim a_n^{b_n}$ where both $a_n$ and $b_n$ approach $0$ in the context of real analysis; and the other is combinatorial definition of exponentiation in the context of set theory or other areas which deal with integers. As you progress in mathematics you will find more and more of these examples, of things which are "indeterminate" in one area but have a clear cut answer in others.

Comment: @Rattanverma With addition defined as repeated succession on the natural numbers, we need only Peano's Axioms to determine the result for every input. Likewise for multiplication defined as repeated addition. This is not the case for exponentiation defined as repeated multiplication. Fortunately, the only indeterminate case would be for $0^0$. We will need more than Peano's Axioms to determine its value.

Comment: OK, thanks to all of you. I got the point.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f: A \to B$ is actually *three* pieces of data: the domain $A$, the codomain $B$, and the rule $f$ which assigns to each element of $A$ an element of $B$, which is a certain subset $R \subseteq A \times B$. Hence a function is a triple $(A, B, R)$.

If the domain and codomain are $\emptyset$, then the relation $R$ is necessarily also $\emptyset$. So $(\emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset)$ is a function. The key point is that a function is not "just" the rule, it also remembers where it's coming from and where it's going to.

Comment: Is set theory a function is **usually** indeed *just* the "rule", i.e. $\subseteq A\times B$. Domain and codomain are easily deducable but are *not* part of the definition. Not the "**usually**". Of course you can include this data if you feel so.

Comment: It does no harm to include them, and (in my opinion) gives a nice argument about why there is exactly one function from $\emptyset$ to any given set.

Comment: Indeed, no harm and a matter of taste. But I fail to see how *this* is it what makes the argument so nice. I mean the first two $\varnothing$ in $(\varnothing,\varnothing,\varnothing)$ are fixed anyway. The uniqueness of the last entry is what makes the result.

Comment: In my experience, people (also myself, a while ago) are usually stuck between deciding whether there is a function or not. The only good answers seem like $0$ or $1$, and this explains why it's $1$: there is a triple satisfying those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: Using the definition of set equality, show that all empty sets are identical, thus there is only one empty set $\emptyset$. Then use the definition of a Cartesian product to prove the existence of the set $f=\emptyset\times\emptyset$. Then use the definition of a function to prove that $f:\emptyset \to \emptyset$. Finally, suppose we have another function $g:\emptyset \to \emptyset$ and prove that $\forall x\in \emptyset: g(x)=f(x)$, thus there is only one function mapping $\emptyset$ to itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this is that the number of functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$, because there are $|A|$ choices to make, each of which has $|B|$ options. In fact, the notation for this set of functions is $B^A$. In your examples, $A$ is empty so we're raising to the power of $0$, giving $1$ function.

Comment: One should not start believing in $0^0=1$ because of this!

Comment: @M.Winter If your exponents are limited to integers or natural numbers, $0^0 = 1$ is a very natural thing to believe. $|B|^{|A|}$ is purely combinatorial in nature, and in combinatorics, $0^0 = 1$ is pretty established.

Comment: @M.Winter: Right. One should believe that because it's true, though. :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok well, no need to discuss this when exponentiation is defined via the cardinality of the set of functions from $0$ to $0$, with $0:=\varnothing$ ;). But outside set theory.... hmmm.

Comment: @M.Winter: I thought that all mathematics was set theory... ;)

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a relation $f\subseteq X\times Y$ which is left-total (i.e., for each $x\in X$ there is some $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$) and right-unique (i.e., if $(x,y_1)\in f$ and $(x,y_2)\in f$, then $y_1=y_2$).
''At least one and at most one'' means ''exactly one''. Thus a relation $f$ is a function if and only if for each $x\in X$ there is exactly one $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\in f$, written $f(x)=y$. This is a basic definition of function, which should help you to understand the case of empty set.

We have $X\times Y=\emptyset$ iff $X=\emptyset$ or $Y=\emptyset$. The empty relation is a function (which is a consequence of the above definitions (which are implications with empty premises).